# Дефолтный конструктор не инициализирует константу

Tags: c++, классы, конструктор

```
const struct A {
    // A() = default;
    int x;
} a;

int main() {}
```

Почему программа не компилируется? Как исправить?

> uninitialized const 'a'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно инициализировать прямо так.

```
const struct A {
    int x = 1; // или любое нужное значение
} a;
```

Способ номер два

```
const struct A {
    int x;
} a {1};
```

В данном случае эти способы дадут одинаковый результат. Но второй способ может быть чуточку осложнен, если переменных в классе много-много.

Comment: Почему первоначальный вариант не компилировался?

Comment: потому что константа должна быть инициализирована, а у int нет дефолтного конструктора. Был бы там какой то класс вместо int (например, std::string), все бы работало.

Answer (score 1):

Независимо от наличия `A() = default;` поле `int x;` будет оставаться неинициализированным, а сам класс - *trivially constructible*. Чтобы этот код заработал, необходимо реализовать дефолтный конструктор, который бы инициализировал поле `A(void): a{42} {}`, либо оставить класс как есть, но инициализировать объект посредством *агрегатной инициализации* `} a{42};`.

Answer (score 0):

`g++` в варианте `C++17` на ваш код отреагировал вот как:

```
some.cpp:4:3: error: uninitialized const ‘a’ [-fpermissive]
 } a;
   ^
some.cpp:1:14: note: ‘const struct A’ has no user-provided default constructor
 const struct A {
              ^
some.cpp:2:5: note: constructor is not user-provided because it is explicitly defaulted in the class body
     A() = default;
     ^
some.cpp:3:9: note: and the implicitly-defined constructor does not initialize ‘int A::x’
     int x;
```

Достаточно явным образом задать дефолтный конструктор:

```
const struct A {
    A() : x(0) {};
    int x;
} a;

int main() {}
```

Как нам [объясняет](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization) CppReference:

> The effects of default initialization are:
>
> - if T is a non-POD (until C++11) class type, the constructors are
>   considered and subjected to overload resolution against the empty
>   argument list. The constructor selected (which is one of the default
>   constructors) is called to provide the initial value for the new
>   object;
> - if T is an array type, every element of the array is
>   default-initialized;
> - otherwise, nothing is done: the objects with
>   automatic storage duration (and their subobjects) are initialized to
>   indeterminate values.

Ваш случай как раз подпадает под *otherwise*.

Comment: Это уже не дефолтный конструктор будет, а пользовательский. Можно ли сохранить дефолтный?

Comment: По-моему тут 1 пункт, а не 3, это же класс

Comment: @Разработчик Путаете термины. Дефолтный - это такой, который можно вызвать с 0 аргументов. То, что вы говорите, это "сгенерированный компилятором".

Comment: @HolyBlackCat понял, в другом ответе уже указали, как сохранить `=default` =  "сгенерированный компилятором" конструктор. Осталось узнать точную причину ошибки (цитату с cppreference)